# event sales_order_shipment_save_after is not working in magento 2.3.4

Tags: magento2, event-observer, submit-shipment

The event sales_order_shipment_save_after is not working in magento 2.3.4 after shipment submit.

event.xml file

SubmitShipmentAfter.php file

addWriter($writer); $logger->info($result); } }

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_order_shipment_save_after">
        <observer name="sales_order_shipment_after_save"
                  instance="Flashdemo\Ship\Observer\SubmitShipmentAfter" />
    </event>
</config>

Comment: <?php

namespace Flashdemo\Ship\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class SubmitShipmentAfter implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
     
      
        $result = "hello"; 
     $result = json_encode($result, true); 
     $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/test.log'); $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger(); $logger->addWriter($writer); $logger->info($result);

     

    }
}

Comment: where you put events.xml in area or global?

Comment: app\code\Flashdemo\Ship\etc\adminhtml

Comment: ok try to move it in "app\code\Flashdemo\Ship\etc" and check once

Comment: I checked ..It's not working..

Comment: could you please updte your code in your question

Comment: i have updated code in my question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all change your `event.xml` to `events.xml` as you are missing s in events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_order_shipment_save_after">
        <observer name="save_sales_order_shipment_after" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\SubmitShipmentAfter" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Then inside `Vendor\Module\Observer\SubmitShipmentAfter.php`

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;

class SubmitShipmentAfter implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        //write your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: still no luck..Actually my file name was already events.xml..